# select some fields of a given table

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to write a method that given:

1. Name of the table T as string.
2. Name of Field to Value F1 as string.
3. Name of Field to Description F2 as string.
4. Name of Field to Information F3 as string.

Return and `IQueryable<TypeItem>` with the records of the table T, and fields F1, F2, F3

TypeItem contain the prop Value, Description and Information as string.

Comment: So what is stopping you? What does "to Value", "to Description" and "to Information" mean?

Comment: It means that in Table T (with Field 1, 2,3 4, 5), I want to use in a call Field1 to Value, Field3 to Description and Field4 for information, but in another call with a table T1 (with Field 1, 2), i want to use Field 1 to Value, and Field 2 for Description and information.

Comment: What is the type of `T`?